# Telerik Freezing header columns

Tags: telerik-reporting

From few days I have been trying to use freezing columns headers. I have followed knowledgebase of telerik reporting services. But still unable to get solutions.

```
    <Table DataSourceName="sqlDataSource1" Width="3.531in" Height="0.48in" Left="0.4in" Top="0.4in" FreezeRowHeaders="False" FreezeColumnHeaders="True" Name="table1">
      <Body>
        <Cells>
          <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="0" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
            <ReportItem>
              <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="1.8in" Top="0.2in" Value="= Fields.FirstName" Name="textBox7" StyleName="" />
            </ReportItem>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="1" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
            <ReportItem>
              <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="1.8in" Top="0.2in" Value="= Fields.InsertDate" Name="textBox2" StyleName="" />
            </ReportItem>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell RowIndex="0" ColumnIndex="2" RowSpan="1" ColumnSpan="1">
            <ReportItem>
              <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="1.8in" Top="0.2in" Value="= Fields.LastName" Name="textBox4" StyleName="" />
            </ReportItem>
          </TableCell>
        </Cells>
        <Columns>
          <Column Width="1.177in" />
          <Column Width="1.177in" />
          <Column Width="1.177in" />
        </Columns>
        <Rows>
          <Row Height="0.24in" />
        </Rows>
      </Body>
      <Corner />
      <RowGroups>
        <TableGroup Name="detailTableGroup">
          <Groupings>
            <Grouping />
          </Groupings>
        </TableGroup>
      </RowGroups>
      <ColumnGroups>
        <TableGroup Name="tableGroup">
          <ReportItem>
            <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="0in" Top="0in" Value="First Name" Name="textBox1" />
          </ReportItem>
        </TableGroup>
        <TableGroup Name="tableGroup1">
          <ReportItem>
            <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="0in" Top="0in" Value="Insert Date" Name="textBox3" />
          </ReportItem>
        </TableGroup>
        <TableGroup Name="tableGroup2">
          <ReportItem>
            <TextBox Width="1.177in" Height="0.24in" Left="0in" Top="0in" Value="Last Name" Name="textBox5" />
          </ReportItem>
        </TableGroup>
      </ColumnGroups>
    </Table>
```

I am using above xml code for telerik reporting.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The configuration seems fine at first glance. Have you checked that the feature is supported (and makes sense) only for displaying in viewers in [interactive mode](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/display-reports-in-applications/interactive-vs.-print-layout)?